localhost:<port> works but <WSL_IP>:<port> does not work
I made a simple script and ran it on a random port inside WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04LTS).
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 6999

Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
print(f"Serving on port {PORT}")
httpd.serve_forever()

The problem is now that when I try to access it from my browser on the host machine using localhost:<port> it works fine, but when I try to access it using <WSL_IP>:<port> it does not work.
The issue is not related to port and with the script, as I tried to run this on multiple ports. I ran other applications with exposed ports as well on my WSL. But none of them worked.
I tried to set some inbound rules but still it did not work.
I tried to curl it on the command prompt but that did not work as well.
I tried uninstalling ubuntu and reinstalling it many times, but that did not work as well.
What is happening here?

Here's a bunch of suggestions
Possibly related to how WSL2 handles network interfaces or firewall rules.
Bind to All Interfaces
Modify your script to explicitly bind to all interfaces
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 6999

Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("0.0.0.0", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
        print(f"Serving on port {PORT}")
        httpd.serve_forever()
        
        

Try disabling UFW, if it's running
sudo ufw disable

Try agin
Check if iptables is blocking the port
sudo iptables -L -n

Check your WSL IP is correct
ip addr show eth0

Or from windows powershell
wsl -d Ubuntu-20.04 ip addr show eth0

Also in powershell (check the connection)
Test-NetConnection <WSL_IP> -Port 6999

It could be your WSL config too
sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf

Add this
[network]
generateResolvConf = true

If you're trying to access it from a remote system try this too
Open Windows Firewall: Control Panel > System and Security > Windows Defender Firewall
Click "Advanced"
Create a new Inbound Rule for the port you're using and allow the connection for all networks

Thank you for the suggestions, I tried all of them and still it did not work out. I do have proxy on my host machine and I have set up http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables on the WSL machine. Could it be related to the proxy?

Wow, if nothing made any changes to the symptoms at all I recommend you try setting it up in a totally vanilla environment (virtual machines, spare laptop etc) with hard coded variables and then introduce any changes (like moving to environment variables) incrementally until you find what's causing the problem. There could also be something broken with your current OS.
